# how to build a tarball for installation of application under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ide, autotools

I am thinking how those open-source applications are developed, like those we download, extract and then use`./configure`, `make` and `make install`.
Now I have my own codes developed with an IDE (netbeans) already. And there is also a makefile generated by the IDE. But I used some libraries in my codes that is too big such as `boost` and `mkl`. I expect the users have them on their computers. If not, they should be reminded to install.
Does this deal with GNU auto-tools?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make configure script check the dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997117/how-to-make-configure-script-check-the-dependencies)

Comment: the answer would be just "Yes" and apointer to the gnu autotools manual

Comment: this is all well documented in the autotools manuals. Answer: yes, that's what they're for.

Comment: since quite complicated makefiles has already been constructed by the IDE, do I need to discard them and use autotools to organize everything from scratch such as the structure of directories of the projects?